# Is Apache compromised? No protocol handler was valid for the URL yandex.ru

Tags: apache, security, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I recently received an abuse report from Amazon (AWS) saying that my server was attempting to log in to forums and such. When I look at my error logs, I have lines and lines of:

```
[proxy:warn] [pid 2916:tid 1668] [client 82.117.234.134:6152] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL yandex.ru:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[proxy:warn] [pid 2916:tid 1668] [client 120.132.54.62:58004] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL www.baidu.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[proxy:warn] [pid 2916:tid 1672] [client 188.173.26.212:52049] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL l9bjkkhaycw6f8f4.soundcloud.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[proxy:warn] [pid 2916:tid 1668] [client 104.199.176.143:56048] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL www.amazon.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[proxy:warn] [pid 2916:tid 1744] [client 119.97.174.200:3700] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL zhifu.99.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[proxy:warn] [pid 2916:tid 1712] [client 113.189.16.238:60122] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL s.youtube.com:443. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf is configured with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName demo.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/sites/mysite/www/" 
    <Directory "D:/sites/mysite/www/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/data" "http://localhost:8080/data/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/data" "http://localhost:8080/data/"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    ErrorLog "logs/demo.mysite.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/demo.mysite.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Starting the server for even just a minute creates about 300+ lines of the above logs. This leads me to several questions:

1. Is my server possibly misconfigured or is it infected with something?
2. Where should I look to find out how it got like this?

UPDATE/EDIT: 
It turns out that I had `ProxyRequests On` because a tutorial said that I have to have it on for Reverse Proxy to work. It's now turned off (`ProxyRequests Off`) and everything is fine. Thanks to [Configuring mod_proxy for Apache to reject wrong domain requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407209/configuring-mod-proxy-for-apache-to-reject-wrong-domain-requests)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure thatyou don't confuse Forward and Reverse Proxies. `ProxyRequests On` is for Forward Proxies. If you don't configure it properly after that, your server is an open proxy for the world. This is what is causing all of the logs is everyone using your (now) proxy server to access the internet.

For Reverse Proxies, make sure that you have `ProxyRequests Off` and then follow the rest of the configuration like adding `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`.

Thanks to [Configuring mod_proxy for Apache to reject wrong domain requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407209/configuring-mod-proxy-for-apache-to-reject-wrong-domain-requests) for pointing out that it is possible to turn your Apache server into an open proxy on accident.